# Doubt about $C_c^\infty$ and boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a function. Is it true that $$\int_0^T f(t)\varphi(t) \leq C\int_0^T|f(t)|$$ if $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$?

I know continuous functions on compact set are bounded. But my doubt is because C_c^\infty means that closure of the set where it's non-zero is compact. So I am not sure.

Comment: You should make some assumptions on $f$ (e.g. integrability), otherwise the lhs may not be defined.

Comment: Yes, the topological support is $\mbox{support} \phi=\overline{\{x\;;\;\phi(x)\neq 0\}}$. And the assumption is that the latter is compact. So the restriction of $\phi$ to this compact is bounded. And outside, it is zero.

Comment: Thank you both for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$, then there exist a compact interval $[a,b] \subset (0,T)$, such that $\varphi(x) = 0$ for $x \not\in[a,b]$. This yields that $\|\varphi\|_{L^\infty(0,T)}$ is bounded. Hence, Hölder's inequality yields your inequality.

Comment: ..................Thanks!